Condition not returning errors (Express.js)
When I call a GET request in Postman with the url "localhost:3000/api/users/id/" without the number of the ID, I'd like to have a return like this one when I call a GET request with the query empty:
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "field",
            "msg": "Must not be empty",
            "path": "filter",
            "location": "body"
        }
}

but insteaded this is the return I have:
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /api/users/id/</pre>
</body>

this the code:
app.get("/api/users/id/:id", findUserIndex, checkSchema(getUserValidationIdSchema), (req, res) => {

    const result = validationResult(req);
    const {userIndex} = req;

    if (!result.isEmpty()) return res.status(400).send({errors: result.array()});

    if (result.isEmpty()) return res.send(users[userIndex]);

})

this is the function finderUserIndex:
const findUserIndex = (req, res, next) => {

    const {params: {id}} = req;
    const parsedId = parseInt(id);

    if (isNaN(parsedId)) return res.sendStatus(400);

    const userIndex = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === parsedId);

    if (userIndex === -1) return res.sendStatus(404);

    req.userIndex = userIndex;
    req.parsedId = parsedId;

    next();

}

and this is the schema get getUserValidationIdSchema:
export const getUserValidationIdSchema = {
    id: {
        notEmpty: {errorMessage: "Must not be empty"},
    }
}


Express uses library, below. And as you can see in description of the package in the part link should direct you to it tells that you can use '?' at the end of route parameter to make it optional.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regex#demonstration-of-processing-a-key-identifier-with-a-quantifier-
So in your case route string should look like below
"/api/users/id/:id?"

